# How to print multiple results with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON output from HPE OneView.  A short example is:

```
{
   "uri": "/rest/server-hardware/*/firmware?start=0&count=32",
   "total": 102,
   "start": 0,
   "prevPageUri": null,
   "type": "sever-firmwareinventory-list-1",
   "category": "server-hardware",
   "count": 32,
   "members": [
     {
         "uri": "/rest/server-hardware/37383638-5A43-3338-313356585742/firmware",
         "type": "server-hardware-firmware-1",
         "category": "server-hardware",
         "serverHardwareUri": "/rest/server-hardware/37383638-5A43-3338-313356585742",
         "serverName": "bb-r2-n12-ilo",
         "serverModel": "Proliant DL380 Gen10",
         "components": [
           {
               "componentVersion": "4.0.4.288",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware",
               "componentKey": "b34e5677-21dc-45d3-872b-42f76fee9053"
           },
           {
               "componentVersion": "U30 v1.46 (10/02/2018)",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "System ROM",
               "componentKey": "aa148d2e-6e09-453e-bc6f-62baa5f5ccc4"
               
           }
       ],
       "created": "2020-07-26T22:01:54.679Z"
     },
     {
         "uri": "/rest/server-hardware/37383638-5A43-3338-313052304C4A/firmware",
         "type": "server-hardware-firmware-1",
         "category": "server-hardware",
         "serverHardwareUri": "/rest/server-hardware/37383638-5A43-3338-313052304C4A",
         "serverName": "bb-r5-n10-ilo",
         "serverModel": "Proliant DL380 Gen10",
         "components": [
           {
               "componentVersion": "4.1.4.296",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware",
               "componentKey": "b34e5677-21dc-45d3-872b-42f76fee9053"
           },
           {
               "componentVersion": "U30 v1.36 (02/15/2018)",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "System ROM",
               "componentKey": null
               
           }
       ],
       "created": "2020-07-26T22:01:54.679Z"
     },
     {
         "uri": "/rest/server-hardware/37313438-3033-5A43-3338-30384D533730/firmware",
         "type": "server-hardware-firmware-1",
         "category": "server-hardware",
         "serverHardwareUri": "/rest/server-hardware/37313438-3033-5A43-3338-30384D533730",
         "serverName": "bb-r3-n1-ilo",
         "serverModel": "Proliant DL560 Gen10",
         "components": [
           {
               "componentVersion": "4.1.4.296",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "Server Platform Services (SPS) Firmware",
               "componentKey": "b34e5677-21dc-45d3-872b-42f76fee9053"
           },
           {
               "componentVersion": "U34 v2.10 (05/21/2019)",
               "componentLocation": "System Board",
               "componentName": "System ROM",
               "componentKey": "aa148d2e-6e08-453e-bc6f-63baa5f5ccc4"
               
           }
       ],
       "created": "2020-07-26T22:01:54.679Z"
     }
   ],
   "modified": "2020-07-27T09:30:55.882Z",
   "nextPageUri": null
}
```

I know I can retrieve the System ROM version for DL380 Gen 10s with: `jq -r '.members[]  | select(.serverModel == "Proliant DL380 Gen10") |  .components[] | select(.componentName == "System ROM") |.componentVersion' firmware`, but I also wanted to print the serverName along with the system ROM version.  Everything I am trying just gives an error.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Building strings is a good trick. You can also build intermediate objects to put things in an easier to understand form if it helps. e.g.

```
$ cat stuff.jq
.members[]
   | select(.serverModel == "Proliant DL380 Gen10")
   | {
       name: .serverName,
       rom: ( .components[] | select(.componentName == "System ROM") | .componentVersion )
       }
   | "The ROM version for \(.name) is \(.rom)"
```

This gives the following as output:

```
$ jq -rf stuff.jq firmware.json 
The ROM version for bb-r2-n12-ilo is U30 v1.46 (10/02/2018)
The ROM version for bb-r5-n10-ilo is U30 v1.36 (02/15/2018)
$
```

Comment: Thanks!  Must have a different jq version.  On our CentOS 6 system, it is 1.3 and on the CentOS 7 system it is 1.6.  1.3 doesn't know '-f' and 1.6 gives a syntax error: `INVALID CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 7:` and then gives the output string.